# Edge (bug) autocomplete / autofill replaces form input default values

Tags: html, autocomplete, microsoft-edge

I'm interested to know why there is not more discussion on this matter. I suppose it might be as simple as "no one really uses edge", but still... This issue is absolutely egregious. Take this HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="Rick">
```

If you do this (as one would do an admin edit user form, for example), and then visit this form in Microsoft Edge, with a "stored address" saved in your profile, you will literally see the input field set to "Rick" for a split-second before Edge decides it knows better and replaces the field's value with whatever your default saved addresses' first name value is (and changes the background of the field to light blue).

The reason this is a massive problem (if I have to spell it out), is that if you have a form in your app like this, where you edit the personal information of other users. When an admin goes in using Edge, and does not know better, they may accidentally replace personal data of every user they edit with their own personal information.

To make it worse, Edge apparently thinks it's above standards compliance and does not honor `autocomplete="off"` nor the commonly accepted work around `autocomplete="new-password"` (which is insane there even has to be a "commonly accepted workaround" if I'm being honest).

I realized this one today; that `autocomplete="new-password"` is being ignored as well, because I had a client using my app report that they edited a user and then the system changed the users password. The new and confirm password fields on the edit user form both employ the aforementioned `autocomplete="new-password"` attribute and now when he (or I in my own testing) open this form in Edge, our saved password for the site is autofilled to these fields upon loading the edit user form.

The workaround I have to use now, is to use `autocomplete="<?= time() ?>-new-password"` for password fields to literally trick Edge into behaving appropriately. This sets the autocomplete value to unique value every time the form is loaded.

How is this acceptable?
How is this not more talked about?

I have reported all of this using Edge's internal feedback mechanism, but I wanted to put something out here in the public view on this. For the record if no other reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can navigate to this location in sequence: Edge settings>Profiles>Personal info>Settings. Then turn off the two options "Autofill passwords and passkeys" and "Automatically fill my info on sign up forms".

Comment: I did not ask how to turn off autofill on Edge. I proposed a discussion about why Edge feels it's OK to overwrite form fields with prefilled default values. The specific example I gave is a user editor form in an admin tool where the form is pre-populated with another user's personal information for an admin to edit. If the admin is using Edge it will replace the users information with the Admin's saved personal data. This is not good behavior. I cannot force people, as the application developer, to turn off their autofill in edge, now can I?